# Horizontal and Vertical tangent lines for a parametric curve

Tags: calculus

```
Consider the parametric curve in the xy-plane given by:
x = t^2 -2t + 4  and y = 2t^3 + 3t^2 -36t -4
Find all equations of the lines which are either horizontal or vertical
tangents to the given curve
```

Okay. The horizontal tangent is when $dx/dt = 0$
      The vertical tangent is when $dy/dt = 0$ I think..

$dx/dt$ = 2t -2

0 = 2t - 2 =>  t = 1;

$dy/dt = 6t^2 + 6t - 36$

$6t^2 + 6t - 36 = 0$

$y = -48, -31$

Should I plug these values back into their corresponding equations? Like: t=1 for the x related eq'. So, when t=1, x is 3.

I don't really know what i'm doing

Comment: a horizontal tangent is a line with as function y = some constant and a vertical tangent is a line ith as function x = some constant, I think wwith these hints you should be able to solve your problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The horizontal tangent line is indeed at the point corresponding to $t=1$. You can easily find the point $(x,y)$ of tangency by plugging in $1$ for $t$.

We get that the point of tangency is $(3,-35)$. So the horizontal tangent line has equation $y=-35$.

For vertical tangency, solve $6t^2+6t-36=0$, or more simply $t^2+t-6=0$. The quadratic factors as $(t+3)(t-2)$. So the $t$ at which we have a vertical tangent line are $t=-3$ and $t=2$.

Separately, for **each** of these, find the point of tangency by substituting. The two vertical tangent lines will have equations of the shape $x=k$. One of them is the line $x=4$. You can find the other one.

Comment: This makes so much sense now. Thank you! Also, unrelated to the question but you have helped me so much on my Combintorics questions. I wanted to let you know that I was able to be a TA for a elementary combinatorics class over the summer because of your help (and others of course). Thanks a million =^.^=

Comment: You are welcome. Now that we have cleared up your questions, I will delete almost all my comments. The system does not like long comment strings. I suggest you do the same. This will make space for any further question you may have!